# Getting CellFormat of a Cell

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm trying to link a Cell object and another CellFormat to determine if a cell is locked.

The CellFormat object, it is getted from the `spreadSheetDocument.workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats` 
collection.

The Cell object, it is getted from the `sheetData.Descendants<Row>()` collection.  In each Row there is a Cell object.

But the question is: where do I get the relationship between the Cell object and the CellFormat object?.

As I understand, within the CellFormat object exists ApplyProtection property and the Protection object, but I don´t know how get the relation between Cell and CellFormat objects.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StyleIndex` of the `Cell` is the index into the `CellFormats` collection. The `CellFormats`, as you point out in your question, contains the `ApplyProtection` and `Protection` properties.

Note that in Excel by default a cell is protected. This means that if `AppyProtection` is `true` and the `Protection` property is null then the cell *is* locked.

Assuming you have a `Cell` object, the following should give you whether or not a cell is locked:

```
//check the styleindex isn't null
if (cell.StyleIndex != null)
{
    //get the CellFormat related to this styleindex
    CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)spreadSheetDocument.workbookPart
                            .WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet
                            .CellFormats.ChildElements[(int)cell.StyleIndex.Value];

    /* the cell is locked if ApplyProtection is true 
    * and either the Protection object is null OR the the Locked property of the Protection object is true
    */
    bool isLocked = cellFormat.ApplyProtection && (cellFormat.Protection == null || cellFormat.Protection.Locked);
}
```

Comment: Great, it works for me!!! But I don´t know why on some times the Protection Property is not null or Protection.Locked could be null or not null, Thank you so much petelids!!!!